# Laravel/Lumen email trimming for api

Tags: php, laravel, validation, lumen

I am developing an api using Laravel/Lumen. I have seen very few users are complaining that even though their emails are completely fine, my api response says `The email must be a valid email address.`

What I have seen is that they are giving a space by mistake after their email like `'noob@user.com '`. As a result the email is not accepted by the system. What I'm using in my code so far is:

```
try {
       $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3|max:40',
        'last_name'  => 'required|min:3|max:40',
        'email'      => 'required|email|unique:clients,email',
        'profile_photo' => ''
         ]);
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            return response()->json($this->clientTransformer->validationFailed($e), 200);
     }
```

I have tried adding the following lines inside the first line of try block but failed to change the $request object property.

```
  try{
    $request->email = trim($request->email, ' '); //<= or
    $request->email = str_replace(' ', '', $request->email); // <= this line

$this->validate($request, [
                'first_name' => 'required|min:3|max:40',
                'last_name'  => 'required|min:3|max:40',
                'email'      => 'required|email|unique:clients,email',
                'profile_photo' => ''
                 ]);
    }
```

but these arent working. this is passing the exact same email to the validate method. Is there any quick way to do it?

Comment: You can use javascript's trim method before sending the request to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$request->replace(array('email' => trim($request->email)));
```

or

```
$request->merge(array('email' => trim($request->email)));
```

Source:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-modify-input-before-validation

Comment: the $request->merge() worked perfectly, the $request->replace() replacing all the array with only one array item(email). which is not expected... anyway.. thanks .. answer accepted